# Migrate View from Oracle to PostgreSQL (with extractvalue() function)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, view, xml

I'm migrating a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL and have a problem with several Views.

I can't find an equivalent function for extractvalue() and xmltype()...

```
NVL(extractvalue(xmltype(METADATA), '/slb/structMap/div/mptr/@OTHERLOCTYPE', 'xmlns="http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"'), '')
```

Here is the full View code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "INGEST_TEST"."AIP_TYPE_INFO" ("AIP_ID", "AIP_VERSION", "TYPE_VALUE") AS 
select
 aip_id,
 aip_version,
case 
    when METADATA is not null then
        NVL(extractvalue(xmltype(METADATA), '/slb/structMap/div/mptr/@OTHERLOCTYPE', 'xmlns="http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"'), '')  
        || '/' ||
        NVL(extractvalue(xmltype(METADATA), '/slb/structMap/div/div[position() = 1]/mptr/@OTHERLOCTYPE', 'xmlns="http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"'), '') 
    else '/'
 end as type_value
from aip ;
```

The Oracle functions are:

`extractvalue()`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm#i1131042

`xmltype()`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm

I either never used those functions and the database I'm migrating. I only have the task to migrate it to PostgreSQL.

The `NVL()` function have its equivalent in PostgreSQL : `COALESCE()`

Does someone have an idea of how to manage this?

Here is an example of the XML content : https://www.dropbox.com/s/59mosi9ewcx67ga/XML_EXEMPLE.xml?dl=0 For this example the view should give me this:

**zeitschrift/zeitschriftennummer**

Comment: I think [`xpath()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: I have looked at xpath() but couldn't manage to do it because it don't use the same arguments.. can you try to show me an example please ?

Comment: You need to provide some sample XML and what you expect as the output. `xpath()` is pretty much the same as Oracle's `extractvalue()`. **[Edit]** your question. Do **not** provide additional information as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres' XML processing is a bit stricter when it comes to XMNL namespaces, so the xpath expression has to prefix every element with the correct namespace.

Based on your sample XML, only the `http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb` namespace is needed, so the view should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW AIP_TYPE_INFO
AS 
select aip_id,
       aip_version,
       case 
         when METADATA is not null then
            concat_ws('/', (xpath('/slb:slb/slb:structMap/slb:div/slb:mptr/@OTHERLOCTYPE', METADATA::xml, t.nsp))[1],
                           (xpath('/slb:slb/slb:structMap/slb:div/slb:div[position() = 1]/slb:mptr/@OTHERLOCTYPE', metadata::xml, t.nsp))[1])
         else '/'
       end as type_value
from aip, 
     (values (array[array['slb', 'http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb']])) as t(nsp);
```

---

The part:

```
, (values (array[array['slb', 'http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb']]))
```

simply creates a single row with an array of the needed namespace definitions. It's there to make the actual `xpath()` call shorter. You can replace both the `t.nsp` inside the function with `array[array['slb', 'http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb']]` if you don't like it.

Note that `xpath()` returns an array of matches. That's why `(xpath(...))[1]` is needed: it simply gets the first match from the array.

`concat_ws()` will cope with NULL values automatically - this is slightly different that the Oracle version. If both xpath() expressions evaluate to `null` the Oracle view would return `'/'` but `concat_ws()` would return an empty string. If you don't want that, you need to use the same approach as in Oracle.

Online example: http://rextester.com/FANG87147

Comment: Thank you for your answere. extractvalue():
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm#i1131042 xmltype():
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm I either never used those functions and the database I'm migrating. I only have the task to migrate it to postgreSQL. The NVL() function have its equivalent in postgreSQL : COALESCE()

Comment: Here is an example of the XML content : https://www.dropbox.com/s/59mosi9ewcx67ga/XML_EXEMPLE.xml?dl=0 For this example the view should give me this :
**zeitschrift/zeitschriftennummer**

Comment: Thank you for your example. I will try to adapt it to work.

Comment: I try to convert another view by following the same logic as your example but I have an error "invalid XPath expression". I think it's because I have another namespace but I don't know how to delcare it..
Can you help me for this one too ?

  EXTRACTVALUE (XMLTYPE (metadata), '/slb/amdSec/techMD/mdWrap/xmlData/nlnz:Object/nlnz:Processes/nlnz:Process[(./nlnz:Type="Originalcreator")]/nlnz:ProcessCreator', 
 'xmlns="http://www.nb.admin.ch/standards/slb" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:nlnz="http://www.natlib.govt.nz/presmet"' ) original_Creator

Comment: This View uses the same XML source as the other one.